# How to Define Attributes of Classes in a Model (Which Requires Updating) in Python?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have the following class, `UNetwork`. It is there for reference. The actual question is related to the second class, `Model`.

```
class UNetwork(object):
    
    nodes = dict()
        
    def _init_(self, nodes):
        self.nodes = nodes
```

Now, the class (`Model`) has the following attributes. How could I define `susceptible_nodes` and `infected_nodes` in the code?:

`network` — an instance of class `UNetwork` taken at instantiation;
`susceptible_nodes` — a list of ids for nodes that are not yet infected; initially includes all nodes from network;
`infected_nodes` — a list of ids for nodes that are infected; initially empty;
`num_infected` — keeps track of the number of infected nodes; initially 0.

```
class Model(object):
    
    def __init__(self, network, susceptible_nodes, infected_nodes, num_infected):
         self.network = UNetwork() 
         self.susceptible_nodes = # unsure how to proceed
         self.infected_nodes = # unsure how to proceed
         self.num_infected = len(self.infected_nodes)
```

Comment: Would they be a list? What would their initial values be? If not empty, where would they got the ID's from?

Comment: @nagyl just extended the initial code to show where the values come from. Essentially just typed in manually for now.

Comment: Would you consider sharing the source on github? It seems interesting, and maybe I could do this part for you.

Comment: @nagyl I just created a new thread to discuss the methods that I'm trying to do following the attributes. Could you provide any insight there? It's the last bit I'm stuck on. You can copy and paste the code from that thread into an editor which should give you as much as I have - I don't have any additional instructions that would benefit from being on GitHub.

Comment: Can't find it. Also I meant continuing this project with more people, not just copying the code. Can you give me a link to the new post?

Comment: @nagyl you can continue it with more people if you wish, but you'd have to upload it to GitHub. Thank you very much - here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64773648/how-could-i-define-these-methods-within-a-class-for-a-model-python?noredirect=1#comment114525645_64773648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If speed is not an issue, they could be simple lists. If it is, you could take a tour in [data structures](https://realpython.com/python-data-structures/).

This list would contain all the keys, that your network's `node` list has, in case they initially all uninfected. If some of them is infected, you coud store that value somewhere, and append all of them to the list by that value. I would recommend storing those values not in a list, but another class, a `Node` class.

```
self.susceptible_nodes = self.network.nodes.keys() #copies the keys (id's) to a list
```

And the second one could be an empty list, since it is initially empty.

```
self.infected_nodes = list()
```

Comment: `#copies the keys (id's) to a list` - since version 3.0 dict.keys() returns a [view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#dict-views) not a list.